# Can I use Burnside's Theorem? Or should I take a different approach for this proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove that:

> If a group $G$ of order $27$ acts on a group $X$ of order $32$, there
>   must be at least one element of $X$ fixed by all points in $G$.

I have attempted to use Burnside's Theorem to no avail:

$$|X/G| = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} |X^g|$$

Then notice that if there is $x$ such that $gx = x$ for all $g$, no fixed points for all $G$ then $|X^g|$ maxes out at $31$ possible fixed points, giving $|X^g|$ and upper bound of $31$. This then evaluates to:

$$|X/G| = \frac{1}{27}\sum_{g \in G} 31$$
$$|X/G| = \frac{1}{27}\times 27\times 31$$
$$|X/G| = 31$$

The original plan was hope this wouldn't be an integer for some reason. This could still happen if I could prove $|X^g|$ dips below $31$ at some point. I don't see any way of doing that, and think I am going down the wrong path. Any push in the correct direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class formula would be a better formula here.

$$|X|=\sum_{x\in S}[G:G_x]$$

where $S$ is a set of orbit representatives.

Since, or $|X|=|X'|+\sum [G:G_x]$ where $X'$ is the set of points fixed by all $g\in G$ and $x$ ranges over orbit reps of non-fixed points. This sum must be divisible by $3$, since $3|[G:G_x]$. So, $|X'|\equiv 32\pmod 3$.

Comment: $S$ is a set of points where each point belongs to a distinct orbit.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just to make sure I am understanding this: $3|[G : G_x]$ since $|G|= 3^3$ And we know that $|G|/|G_x|$ must be an integer, resulting in either $3^3$, $3^2$ or $3$, hence $|X'| \equiv 32 \mod 3$ meaning $|X'|$ has a strong lower bound of at least $2$ (since 32 mod 3 = 2)?

Comment: Yes. You've got that right. In general, if $G$ is a $p$-group acting on a set $X$, $|X'|\equiv|X|\pmod p$ by the same argument.